# Steganography Code in PowerShell is not working correctly

Tags: powershell, syntax, syntax-error, steganography

In my IT class, we are currently working on Steganography and I got this code for PowerShell I am working with to hide a message in an image. The code works but our instructions say to remove a part because it is unnecessary. But if I remove this part as we are instructed to the code runs differently but then tells me there is a syntax error to the command and is not writing the message to the image. This is the code we are working with

```
function Hide-Msg {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [string]$Message
    )

    # Prompt the user for the message if not provided as an argument
    if (-not $Message) {
        $Message = Read-Host "Enter the message to hide"
    }

    # Prompt the user for confirmation before proceeding
    $confirmation = Read-Host "Are you sure you want to hide the message in '$Path'? (Y/N)"
    if ($confirmation -ne "Y") {
        Write-Host "Operation canceled."
        return
    }

    echo "`n`n $Message" > $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\foo.txt

    cmd.exe /c copy /b "$Path" + "$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\foo.txt" "$Path"

    rm $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\foo.txt -r -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

# Example usage:
# Hide-Msg -Path "C:\example.txt" -Message "This is a hidden message"
```

**The part we are supposed to remove is this **

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
    [string]$Path,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
    [string]$Message
)
```

But then first of all the [CmdletBinding()] gives me an error so I removed the () but that led me to the problem that it does prompt me and asks me for the message I want to write and asks to confirm but eventually gives me the syntax error before it writes it. How can I fix this problem without completely changing the code?

I added

```
param (
        [string]$Path,
        [string]$Message
    )
```

to define the parameter but that basically brings me back to square one and to the code running the same as with the "unnecessary" code piece. Per instructions, it was supposed to run differently and write the message to the image.

Comment: When you remove the parameter declaration you're no longer able to provide a path (*a value for `$path`*), nor is it statically declared anywhere else for it to be referenced properly. The last issue I can see is the concatenating of `$path` and your path to `foo.txt`. It should be wrapped in a grouping expression so it can be interpreted by PowerShell first, then passed as single value to `cmd.exe`. Otherwise, it's being read as all part of the same command so each argument (*including the concatenation*) is read as a separate token to be passed to `cmd.exe` to execute.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to have a read about PSScriptAnalyzer - it's a linting tool for PowerShell that helps you write more maintainable code. Some of the rules might be a matter of personal preference, but it would flag up the [```AvoidUsingCmdletAliases```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/avoidusingcmdletaliases?view=ps-modules) rule for your use of ```echo``` and ```rm```, for example. If you use an IDE like VSCode to write your scripts it will show these warnings automatically as you type...

Comment: Can you elaborate on _why_ you're supposed to remove the specified part of the code? What is the goal? @AbrahamZinala, good points, but note that in this case the `+` is actually meant for `cmd.exe`'s `copy` command, to copy two files into a single target file (that's the steganography part).

Comment: @mklement0, thank you. That was something I was curious about and figured someone would correct me sooner or later

Comment: I will check this tool out. This sounds like a very helpful tool.
@mklement0 The class I'm taking is a beginner's IT class and this week's topic is Steganography in our instructions, it said that after we added a user prompt to our code using a generative AI. This snippet of code is now a piece of unnecessary code and we should remove it. But I feel like it is not the case and that it is indeed needed or otherwise it is not running properly.

Comment: I think you meant to mention @mclayton, not me, with respect to [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer). Indeed, with the code as written, the only way you could omit the parameter declarations if you unconditionally prompted for _both_ `$Message` and `$Path` values.